# cakePHP - many to many - accessing players and showing them in the rounds view

Tags: php, cakephp, many-to-many, cakephp-model

I have a rounds table who has many videos. My videos table has a many to many relationship with players. In my rounds view I show the related videos, but I'm trying to show the related players of a video as well in the rounds view. But I'm failing in that regard. I'm posting the code that works, that is the rounds view where I show the related videos.

How can I access the players that are related to videos in the rounds view? This is bugging me for a while now!

rounds table :

```
round_id    int(11)         
round_name  varchar(45)
tournament_id   int(11)
```

videos table :

```
video_id    int(11)
video_title varchar(45)
video_date  date
video_scoreA
video_scoreB
video_url   varchar(255)
tournament_id   int(11)
round_id    int(11)
```

players table :

```
player_id   int(11)
player_firstname    varchar(45)
player_surname  varchar(45)
player_birthDate    date
player_turnedPro    year(4)
player_nickname varchar(45)
player_nationality  varchar(45)
player_flag varchar(255)
player_highestBreak varchar(45)
player_highestRanking   int(11)
player_centuryBreaks    int(11)s
player_careerWinnings   varchar(55) 
player_worldChampion    varchar(45)
player_image    varchar(255)
player_category varchar(45)
```

players_videos table :

```
id  int(11)
video_id    int(11)
player_id   int(11)
```

Roundscontroller view action :

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Round->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid round'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Round.' . $this->Round->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->set('round', $this->Round->find('first', $options));
}
```

Rounds view.ctp :

```
<table cellpadding = "0" cellspacing = "0">
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo __('Video Id'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo __('Video Title'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo __('Video Date'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo __('Video ScoreA'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo __('Video ScoreB'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo __('Video Url'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo __('Tournament Id'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo __('Round Id'); ?></th>
        <th class="actions"><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($round['Video'] as $video): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $video['video_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $video['video_title']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $video['video_date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $video['video_scoreA']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $video['video_scoreB']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $video['video_url']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $video['tournament_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $video['round_id']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ContainableBehavior is what you want: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

so go to your AppModel and add `public $actsAs = array('Containable');` to it.

In the controller method add the `contain` key to the options-array:

```
$options = array(
    'conditions' => array('Round.' . $this->Round->primaryKey => $id),
    'contain' => array(
        'Video' => array('Player'),
    ),
)
```

In your view, you can access the first Player-name from the first Video like:

```
echo $round['Video'][0]['Player'][0]['player_surname'];
```

or with foreach-loops:

```
foreach ($round['Video'] as $video){
    echo $video['video_title'];
    foreach ($video['Player'] as $player){
        echo $player['player_surname'];
    }
}
```